# ASP.Net Custom 404 Error

Tags: asp.net, web-config, http-status-code-404, custom-error-pages

I am trying to display a custom 404 error in asp.net. However, the page I want to display is not a static page and is not a .aspx page it is a page that is generated from the database that is created by our users.

So the path for the page would be /page/404.

I have tried manipulating the web config however I either get a server error or a 302 to 200 redirect or just a 200 page found.

I am able to get the 404 error to work if I use a static page or a .aspx page but not if I use a page from the database that uses a .Master template.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Create a service that generates the page from the database. Map the URL /page/404 to this service.

Comment: Can you elaborate how this *page from database* works? Since you can have a `.aspx` page as your 404 page, I can't see where you could have issues with that.

Comment: The issue is that our software is a CMS, our 404 pages will vary greatly from customer to customer so a static 404 page won't work. So, the 404 page is simply another page in our database and we want to use that page as the 404 display instead of a static one.

Comment: Is the "page" file bytes or HTML or.. in the database? Are you actually loading a file or the content for the file from the database?